# Switching from bash to csh prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, console, csh

I work on linux console and need to work on csh prompt. However the default prompt is bash and I have to give the command csh to change the mode. The reason for switching the prompt is that there are some background files which run only in csh prompt.

Example:

```
-bash-4.1$ ade useview shkanodi_sqlplus_v1

bash: /usr/local/nde/setup/nderc.csh: line 44: syntax error near unexpected toke                                                                                                                     n `('
bash: /usr/local/nde/setup/nderc.csh: line 44: `foreach file (.ndeprodrc .ndevie                                                                                                                     wrc)'
bash: /etc/skel/cshrc-DEFAULT: line 20: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Explanation: 
In the above example the command `ade useview shkanodi_sqlplus_v1` is not executed properly in bash prompt and I first have to give csh command and then run the command. I would like to bypass giving csh command.

Comment: You are running `csh` scripts with `bash`. Don't. Those are two completely different programs.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It was the background process that was running the csh scripts. I know that those are different programs and we cannot run csh scripts with bash. The intention is to bypass running the command csh before executing the command that calls the csh scripts in the background. It is now done by executing csh command in the background script only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Make sure you've got csh installed.

2.Learn the location of csh:

```
which csh
or    
whereis csh
```

Below, I'll assume the location is /bin/bash.

a) If you have administrative rights, just run as root:

```
usermod -s /bin/csh YOUR_USERNAME
```

(replacing YOUR_USERNAME with your user name).

b) If you don't have adm. rights, you can still just run csh --login at login, by putting the below line at the end of your .profile (in your home directory) :

```
setenv SHELL /bin/bash
exec /bin/csh --login
```

Refrence : [bash from csh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20629/how-to-change-from-csh-to-bash-as-default-shell)

Comment: Thanks Ani. I just added the line exec /bin/csh at the end of the .bashrc file in the home directory. It solved the problem.